# outputting strings and function outputs in Python

Tags: python

I am coding a simple program to add all positive integers not greater than a given integer n. My code:

```
print("Enter an integer:")
n=input()

def add(k):
    sum=0
    for i in range(k+1):
        sum=sum+i
    return sum
    
#print("1+2+3+...+"+str(n)+"="+str(add(n)))

print(add(100))
```

The function works.

Why does the line in the one line comment not work, if I remove the hash tag? It should - there is a concatenation of four strings. Thank you.

EDIT: the whole output:

```
Enter an integer:
12
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in add
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: You should rename that `sum` variable as that is a reserved keyword in python

Comment: `input()` returns string values, so `n` is a string, so the for loop tries to evaluate `k+1` where k is a string.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim, it's a built-in function, not a reserved keyword. If it was a keyword, the code would raise a syntax error

Comment: @ForceBru you're right. I said the the wrong thing, just wasn't thinking. But the point still stands that is should be renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` returns a string. You are passing `n=input()` which is a string so it is not working as expected.
change it to `n=int(input())`

Also `sum` is a reserved keyword and it will be best to change that to a different name

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string, so `add(n)` will look something like `add("1234")`. Then, `range(k+1)` inside the function will be `range("1234" + 1)`, but `"1234" + 1` is an error since it's not possible to add a string and a number.

Answer (score 1):

The problem exists in your input, it's current data type is `str`, and must be converted into `int`.

Also, it's best if you use `.format()` when printing strings.

```py
print("Enter an integer:")
n = int(input())

def add(k):
    sum=0
    for i in range(k+1):
        sum=sum+i
    return sum
    
print("1 + 2 + 3 + ... + {} = {}".format(n, add(n)))
```